# Best single word to mean someone who builds, tests and reports on something?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a title for someone who builds things simply to test whether they are as good as they say they are expected to be.  For example, say someone creates an article or video that claims "if you do this then you will achieve this or have this".  I need a word for someone who does what they have said "builder/engineer" and then reports the actual results "tester/surveyor/reporter".

I've thought of debunker, but that is a bit negative, and I don't want the title to be someone people might immediately think "oh he's trying to prove me wrong".  I want it to come across as verification or validation.  But it isn't just about the testing, it is about the recreation of it too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're describing someone whose job is to assess (and measure to some degree) the validity of the system so I would go with either "validator" or "accessor". If you're describing someone who assesses the veracity of statements, I would go with a "fact-checker". Though that word often carries certain connotations so perhaps an "authenticator" (such as a person who accesses whether diamonds are real).

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for non-code like that. Use quotation marks or emphasis.

Comment: @Laurel It was to my understanding that the formatting is for monospaced, preformatted text. Not necessarily code. Particularly because on a SE site that actually writes code (such as Stack Overflow or Code Golf) they don't use those tags for writing code...

Comment: It's inline code, which in the compiled HTML is `<code></code>`. See this [reference on using code spans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/323179) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The verb is more common than the agent noun, but one possibility is **appraiser.**

> *appraise* [verb] [with object]
>
> 1 Assess the value or quality of.
>
> - *there is a need to appraise existing techniques*

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/appraise)]

> *appraiser*: one who estimates officially the worth or value or quality of things

[[WordNet](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/appraiser)]

There are stipulative definitions (often with the employee being the focus of appraisal) making this suggestion less than optimal, as well as the 're-creating to test a claim' being only implicit in certain examples ... but expecting all the qualifications in a single word is highly optimistic.